# Screen turn off/crazy when I adjust my screen brightness continuously on a Dell Studio 1558

Tags: 12.04, dell, unity-2d, radeon

I have a Dell Studio 1558, With a Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series on Unity 2D.

After a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04, I rebooted and logged in to my Ubuntu.The screen was too bright, So I press <kbd>F4</kbd> to decrease the brightness. But when I pressed <kbd>F4</kbd> repeatedly to decrease the brightness to 0, My Laptop screen turned off, I had to shutdown my laptop by pressing the power button.

So I tested it again few times and got the same result, I tried to install the Additional Drivers (ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX), Tested it again, The screen didn't turned off but go crazy, And I still had to shutdown my laptop.

I think may be this is happening due to the <kbd>F4</kbd> key, I install `xbacklight` and used it to dim my screen brightness. If I try to set `xbacklight -set 50` and then 40-30... my screen still dead!

Not just the screen is dead, I must say the Laptop is dead, I can open any command prompt. Event when I try to close the lid, The Laptop doesn't suspend.

- Just tried to install Gnome-Shell, every thing seems to work OK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work with `acpi_backlight=vendor` boot option.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+question/196784

- [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)

Comment: well, can you tell me where to add the line?

Comment: works like a charm