# What if I remove the additional graphic driver?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, vga

I have an Dell laptop with ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series] and proprietary FGLRX graphic card installed.
The card give me [some issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131967/screen-turn-off-crazy-when-i-adjust-my-screen-brightness-continuously-on-a-dell/140422#140422) that I think I can't do anything. And I don't need it, I just use my laptop to browsing web for youtube video, text edit and no more. So I wonder if I remove the driver so the card no more effect to my sytem, is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternativly try the open source ati drivers, which would probably get installed / be used as soon as you remove the proprietary drivers (I think that happens, at least with my NVIDIA card).

You might need to set nomodeset in grub to boot or you will only get a black screen. Google "nomodeset ubuntu" or something similar to find out more 'bout it!